# Justify Text in CSS

Tags: css

I'd like to align my blog post text so that the paragraph is flush on both sides by increasing letter spacing. Is there a way to do this in CSS? I've tried `text-align: justify;` and I've tried adding letter spacing properties. Neither seems to work. If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

I'm very new to CSS but I work in print media, where it is called kerning. The spaces between the letters are selectively spaced to create more visually appealing text and the paragraph aligns on both sides. Right now I have created a track element, which just creates overall space between letters, which is not the same as kerning. I don't know what its referred to in programming though.

This is what I had:

```
.the-content {
width: 540px;
text-align: justify;
}
```

**This is what worked:**

```
#content p {
margin-bottom: 11px;
color: #555;
text-align: justify;
```

Comment: That should do it. Are your sure your selector is in order?

Comment: Can you post your code? hard to tell without it.

Comment: It's funny, I've never been able to get `text-align: justify;` to work either... but then again - I never tried very hard.

Comment: @Madmartigan - [How hard could it possibly be](http://jsfiddle.net/4BKUE/)?

Comment: This is a block-level property. You have to apply it to a block-level element that contains your text. If it's not already inside of a `<p>` or other block-level element, the easiest thing to do is wrap your text inside of a `<div>` tag and apply the `text-align: justify;` attribute to that. Post the relevant portions of your HTML and CSS code and someone will be able to tell you exactly how to fix it.

Comment: @JosephSilber: The links is 404. I'm not kidding though, I've never gotten it to work that I can remember, even tried setting the `justify` property (which I just learned of). jsfiddle hasn't been online today, got another demo? I can't even find an example on the web of it working (on FF9 or Chrome).

Comment: @Madmartigan - Weird. jsfiddle works for me. They have been offline, but they've been back up for quite a while already (and even when they were offline you could still get read-only access). [Here is the same thing in jsbin](http://jsbin.com/anijic/edit#preview).

Comment: @JosephSilber: I just had a moment of clarity:  for years I've had the wrong idea of what justified text is, and never noticed that it was actually working. Wow. Thanks. I guess I never noticed because I've never wanted to use it.

Comment: On JSBin instead. http://jsbin.com/esuqad/

Comment: @Blowski Yes that's what I'm trying to achieve. So far I'm stumped.

Comment: @Cody Gray Thanks! I put it inside of the block-level element that had the text and it worked!

Comment: This is not not called kerning, which is something entirely different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

More than likely, you're trying to justify an inline element, such as a span.  Justification can only work when aplied to a block level element.

If you would like further help, then you will have to post an example of what you're doing.

Comment: You're right! This worked     #content p {
margin-bottom: 11px;
color: #555;
    text-align: justify;